# How to call to get the source page which requets another JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to know how to get the name of the page that requests another JSF page to further call specific methods in the bean according to the source page, i don't want to use `<f:event type="preRenderView"
                    listener="#{beanName.preRender}" />` because the specified page has components that's rendered according to the source page

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know this has to be handcoded and the best way to do it is probably in a `@WebFilter`. and `request.getRequestURI();`

Then simply save the pages in a suitible fashion for example `ArrayDeque`.

The ArrayDeque could for example be saved in a `@SessionScoped` bean.